# Android studio not recognizing a package even after changing targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I had an existing Android Studio project which was for target sdk version 17. I had to use the BluetoothGattCharacteristic package in the same project. This package was introdcued in API level 18. 
I hence did the following:

> - changed the targetSdkVersion to 18 in the AndroidManifest.xml
> - changed the targetSdkVersion to 18 in the build.gradle file.
> - downloaded APIs for level 18 from Android SDK Manager.

Even after doing the above, if I use the 'import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic' in a class, I get the error 'Cannot resolve symbol BluetoothGattCharacteristic'.

Is there something else that I should be doing?

Comment: You should change the **Compile Sdk Version** to 18. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the Compile Sdk Version to 18 and must have to sync the gradle**

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thanks. And for those who actually did another Google Search to find how to change the compile sdk version(like me),  you have to go to File->Project Structure-> Properties -> Compile Sdk Version